# AngularJS Website, Cache a version number

Tags: angularjs, caching

I made a site using angularJS.
But i got a problem.

my users gets lots of errors curse they have a old cached version of the site,

So what i wanna do, is to somehow create a version number for the cache, so when the users calls in with the error, i can ask what version they are using to see if the cached site is to old, an ask them to empty the cached.

Anyone know how this can be done? I'm not looking to handle my cache, just show a number, displaying the cached version.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable that is printed to console which represents the site version, which of course will be visible only from the time you'll add it.

However, old cached versions of sites are a solved problem that your users shouldn't experience at all. It is solvable by adding a fingerprint to the js files you're requesting (adding a suffix which is the checksum\last update time of the file), and not having cache at all on the main html which mentions the js files. Same goes to css or other files that are likely to change from version to version.

Depending on your static files server, there are plugins and modules that are able to take care of this problem. On NginX, the most popular is PageSpeed:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/

A more detailed description to what I wrote above (and pagespeed implements) can be found at "Invalidating and updating cached responses" on this guide:
https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses

Comment: This fingerprint on the js files, can you give a sample what it would look like? and can i use this "Fingerprint", as a globle variable, so i can just change the value one place, an it would change it for all the js files?

Comment: If i can use a global variable, this would also make it possible to show a version number of the cache in on of the corners of the site,

Comment: Okay. So i minify my scripts using asp.net. an this use the "Fingerprint" solution, BUT. it's not updating the client cache even when the fingerprint is change, So back to stage one, A way to show a version number of the cache